# Auto layout - Collapsable views (vertically)

Tags: ios, autolayout, collapsable

I'd like to create an "adding a new credit card viewController".
We don't want to aggravate users with all of the required fields presented at once.
This action contains several steps.
On each step the view-controller reveals a new subview (which contains one or more textfields) and collapses an old one (the current text field after it's text is validated).

1. I've created the ViewController on the storyboard. and placed all of its subviews one above the other.
2. I've created all of the constraints on the storyBoard, each subviews' clips to the above subview etc'.

i.e:

```
NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintsWithVisualFormat:
        @"V:|[titleView]-[subtitleView]-[amountView]-[cardNumView]-[cardsImagesView]-[mmYYCvvView]-[billingInfoView]-[buttomView]|"
    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
    metrics:nil
    views:variableBindings] mutableCopy];
```

3. Each of these subviews contain a height constraint.
4. In each step one of the height constraints are set to zero and another one is changed from zero to the required height.

i.e:

```
self.hgtCrtMMYYCvv.constant = showFields? 50 : 0;
self.hgtCrtBillingInfo.constant = showFields? 140 : 0;
self.mmYYCvvView.hidden = !showFields;
self.billingInfoView.hidden = !showFields;
```

I got two issues:

- Without calling `layoutIfNeeded` the initial layout was valid but did not change after changing the height constraints.
- Calling `layoutIfNeeded` did not clip the bottom view to the last visible one - placed it at the bottom of the view as if all the subviews appear at once, but since some are hidden a gap was created.
  changing the height constraint of the subviews was applied on the screen but still the gap stayed.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

> Calling "layoutIfNeeded" did not clip the bottom view to the last visible one - placed it at the bottom of the view as if all the subviews appear at once

Look at your constraints. You have pinned the bottom of the bottom view to the bottom of its superview! So its bottom *must* appear at the bottom of the superview, since that is what you instructed it to do.

Indeed, I am surprised that your constraints work at all. You have basically overdetermined them. If you give every field a height *and* pin its top and bottom, for *every* field, then it will be impossible to satisfy your constraints unless you are very lucky. The height of the superview is fixed, so your constraints would have to add up perfectly to that height.

I'm going to suggest a complete alternative approach, which I think you will find easier. Instead of messing with individual constants, plan what the correct (not overdetermined) constraints would be for each possible situation, and store those constraints in properties. Now when you want to hide/reveal a field, you just remove all the constraints and swap in another set.

This will also solve the `layoutIfNeeded` problem.

It happens that I have an actual example showing how to do this. (It is written in Swift, but I'm sure you can compensate mentally.) In my example code, we have three rectangles; I then remove one rectangle and close the gap between the remaining two. The preparation of two sets of constraints is tedious but elementary:

```
    let c1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(20)-[v(100)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["v":v1]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]
    let c2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(20)-[v(100)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["v":v2]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]
    let c3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-(20)-[v(100)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["v":v3]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]
    let c4 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-(100)-[v(20)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["v":v1]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]
    let c5with = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v1]-(20)-[v2(20)]-(20)-[v3(20)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["v1":v1, "v2":v2, "v3":v3]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]
    let c5without = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v1]-(20)-[v3(20)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["v1":v1, "v3":v3]) as [NSLayoutConstraint]

    self.constraintsWith.extend(c1)
    self.constraintsWith.extend(c2)
    self.constraintsWith.extend(c3)
    self.constraintsWith.extend(c4)
    self.constraintsWith.extend(c5with)

    self.constraintsWithout.extend(c1)
    self.constraintsWithout.extend(c3)
    self.constraintsWithout.extend(c4)
    self.constraintsWithout.extend(c5without)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsWith)
```

But the payoff comes when it is time to swap the middle view in or out of the interface: it's trivial. Just remove or insert it, and then remove all constraints and now insert the complete new set of constraints appropriate to the situation, which we have already prepared:

```
@IBAction func doSwap(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.v2.superview != nil {
        self.v2.removeFromSuperview()
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraintsWith)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsWithout)
    } else {
        self.view.addSubview(v2)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(self.constraintsWithout)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(self.constraintsWith)
    }
}
```

The *preparation* of the multiple sets of constraints is tedious but can be done by rule, i.e. the constraints can be "machine-generated" in a loop (writing this is left as an exercise for you). Swapping constraints in and out is again according to a simple rule, since only one set will be right for the particular set of fields you wish to show/hide. So once this is set up it will be much simpler and more maintainable than what you are doing now.